# Measure spaces proof $A,B \in\mathcal{B}$ and $\mu (A\Delta B) = 0$, then $\mu (A) = \mu (B)$ .

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $A\Delta B = (A$ \ $B) \cup (B$ \ $A)$. Show that

> If $A,B ∈\mathcal{B}$
>   and $\mu(A\Delta B) = 0$, then
>   $\mu(A) = \mu(B)$ .

Answer (score 3):

In this answer $A\Delta B$ denotes the set $(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$.

$$\mu(A)=\mu(A\cap B)+\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(A\cap B)$$
where the last equality follows from: $$0\leq\mu(A\setminus B)\leq\mu(A\Delta B)=0\text{ hence }\mu(A\setminus B)=0$$
(this is based on $A\setminus B\subseteq A\Delta B$)

Similarly we find that $\mu(B)=\mu(A\cap B)$ and combining the results we find:$$\mu(A)=\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(B)$$

Answer (score 1):

From $\mu(A\triangle B) =0$ it follows that $\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(B\setminus A) = 0$. We have also $$\mu(A \cup  B) = \mu(B) + \mu(A\setminus B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B\setminus A)$$ so $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$.